# bash: how to compute average of different columns?

Tags: bash, awk, time, mean

I am writing a script for automatically computing average runtime.

First I need to run `$ time ./foo.py` for 100 times and save output to file `time.txt` (working)

```
$ for i in `seq 100`; do { time ./foo.py; } 2>> time.txt; done
```

Output looks as follows

```
time ./foo.py
real    0m0,030s
user    0m0,030s
sys     0m0,000s
[...]
```

Runtimes from different scripts are in the same file. Each entry starts with `time ./foo.py`, followed by 100 "triplets" of `real`, `user` and `sys`.

Now, if possible, I would love to have the script automatically compute the average runtime for each tested file by using all 100 "triplets", and neatly returning only one "mean triplet".

I have thought about maybe using `awk` to calculate the mean, like this

```
awk '{ total += $2 } END { print total/NR }' time.txt
```

But the command would need to be adapted to fit my needs - after all, only the parts after the `,` (e.g. `,030s`) may be used for computation and the `s` would also need to be disregarded.

Since I do not know how to achieve this objective, I thought to ask the community.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier if you tell `time` to output the time info in POSIX format:

```
awk '/^real/ { totalReal += $2 } /^user/ { totalUser += $2 } /^sys/ { totalSys += $2 } END { print "realAvg " totalReal/(NR/4) "\n" "userAvg " totalUser/(NR/4) "\n" "sysAvg  " totalSys/(NR/4) }' time.txt
```

Prints output as follows:

```
realAvg 12.62
userAvg 27
sysAvg  3.8
```

Explanation:

- Basically, tell `awk` to go through each line in the file, and if the line starts with `real`, add that to the `totalReal` variable, same for `user` and `sys`.  So, basically, keep a running total of each of the three "types".
- At the end, simply print the the three running totals, divided by the number of lines *divided by 4*.  This is because you want each "set" of 4 lines to count as 1 instance, and awk's `NR` just counts the number of lines.

Comment: Thank you very much! The idea with POSIX and keeping track of instances is really great. I'll try that out as soon as I have got the time. If I get it to work, I'll accept your answer. Thanks again!